# Laravel softDelete migration issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

We recently tried to add a soft delete to an existing model through a new migration. Everything works fine locally, but it was failing our unit Test because it could not find the deleted_at column of the new migration.

Our unit tests rebuild the database each time, so it will run all the migrations and seed the tables.

After a little bit of an investigation, he failure stemmed from a previous migration that performed referenced that table and pulled data from it.

Initial Migration code:

```
Schema::create('inclusions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('affiliate_id')->index();
            $table->string('owner_type', 50);          
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('affiliate_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('affiliates');
        });
```

Down the road, we created a new table that referenced this table and another and populated the data.

```
Schema::create('inclusion_vertical', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('inclusion_id');
            $table->foreignId('vertical_id');

            $table->primary(['inclusion_id', 'vertical_id']);

            $table->foreign('inclusion_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('inclusions');

            $table->foreign('vertical_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('verticals');
        });

        $verticals = Vertical::all();

        // Link the inclusions to the new verticals table
        Inclusion::each(function (Inclusion $inclusion) use ($verticals) {
            $verticalIds = json_decode($inclusion->getAttribute('verticals'));

            $inclusion->verticals()->sync($verticals->whereIn('external_id', $verticalIds));
        });
```

Recently we added the migration to add soft deletes on that inclusions table (as well as updating the model itself to use softDeletes.

```
Schema::table('inclusions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

So because the model says there should be softDeletes (the deleted_at column) and there's a migration that attempts to select data from that table using eloquent, it fails the test because the deleted_at column doesn't exist.

My question becomes, is there a solution for this? The one we came up with is to update the 2nd migration and change the query so it doesn't use eloquent or maybe append ->withTrashed (which would bypass the deleted_at), but there seems to be some conflict in terms of whether you should ever edit previous migrations. We want to avoid a solution where we have to put a note in and change things depending on whether we are simply doing the unit test or re-deploying (i.e. new local host user).

Just for some clarification, here are the steps to reproduce:

- Create a fresh table (Table A) in one migration (without soft
  deletes).
- Load data from it into another table in a second migration
  (using eloquent) Update the model for Table A so it uses soft deletes
- Create a migration for Table A that adds the soft delete
- Run a fresh rebuild.

It works perfectly fine on local and staging because the model update and migration to add the softDelete don't have issues. But it's failing the unit tests (and presumably any fresh builds) because it starts the migrations from the first one and goes down the list. And because the model says it uses soft deletes, when it gets to the migration to load data from one table to another, it can't do it because the migration that adds the soft delete happens later on.

Comment: Have you tried to refresh DB in your **LOCALHOST**? First backup your DB so that it will not be lost. then run `php artisan migrate:fresh` then check your `inclusions` table to see if soft_delete was actually created. **BACKUP DB BEFORE THIS** then just return DB after checking.

Comment: It is quite hard to understand your problem, maybe someone can update your question.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth I have not, but I presume it would fail in the same way because of the order in which things are done.  I have a solution for it that doesn't impact anything and passes our unit tests and works on a fresh build, but it involves editing the migration that loads the data and using withTrashed, which bypasses the deleted_at (or just changing it to a raw SQL statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is you added soft deletes to a model after the initial migration, and an intermediate migration is accessing the table and causing errors?

You can just use the query builder which does not use Eloquent bits and pieces like soft deletes:

```php
$verticals = Vertical::all();
DB::table('inclusions')
    ->get()
    ->each(
        fn (Inclusion $inc) => $inc->verticals()
            ->sync($verticals->whereIn('external_id', json_decode($inc->verticals)))
    );
```

But since you're presumably deploying this code into a new environment without any records, the easy solution seems to be to just remove this code from the migration altogether. The whole point of code like this is to patch in new relationships when you have existing data.

Generally migrations don't get touched, but there's no point in being religious about it, especially when a migration that once had to deal with live data is now used only in new installations.

One other note is that you can [squash your migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#squashing-migrations) to prevent the migration files from being individually run.

Comment: Thanks, ill have to discuss it with my team. Adding withTrashed worked, but I was curious if there might be another way that avoids altering a previous migration, because the few solutions I was pondering there was always a "you shouldn't change older migrations" comment in there.

Comment: As I said there’s a difference between applying a migration to existing data in a live migration versus reusing those same migrations in a new install. Different use cases need different code.